# How to prepare data for dynamic highchart using mysql in meteor js?

Tags: javascript, meteor, highcharts

I am creating my first highchart in MeteorJS. I am using mysql. 
I have added highchart and numtel packages.

Following code I have used.

**server.js**

```
var liveDb = new LiveMysql({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'password',
    database: 'database_name'
});

var closeAndExit = function () {
    liveDb.end();
    process.exit();
};

// Close connections on hot code push
process.on('SIGTERM', closeAndExit);
// Close connections on exit (ctrl + c)
process.on('SIGINT', closeAndExit);

Meteor.publish('getAllUsers', function () {
    return liveDb.select(
        'SELECT name,total FROM table_name ORDER BY total DESC',
        [{table: 'table_name'}]
    );
});
```

**client.js**

```
allUsers = new MysqlSubscription('getAllUsers');

function createHighChart() {
  $('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
      type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
      text: 'All Users'
    },
    xAxis: {
      type: "category"
    },
    series: [{
        data: **?????** // What should be here to display data.?
      }]
  });
}

/*Template.allUsersTemp.onCreated(function() {
});*/


Template.allUsersTemp.onRendered(function() {
  this.autorun(() => {
    createHighChart();
  });
});
```

I want to prepare json data and bind to series. Please help me to make this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there should be empty data and you can listen on changes:

```
series: [{
    data: []
  }]
```

And:

```
allUsers.addEventListener('changed', function (diff, data) {
  chart.series[0].setData(data);
});
```

Note: `data` should be format required by Highcharts ([docs](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series%3Cline%3E.data)) so you may need to preprocess your data.

Comment: Thanks Pawel. You guide me on Event change direction. Can i extract name and total as following

var json = [{
    "name": "A",
    "total": "40"
}, {
    "name": "B",
    "total": "70"
}, {
    "name": "C",
    "toatal": "90"
}];

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to achieve. In Highcharts, there should be "`y: value`", not "total". Also, number should be actually a number, not a string. For example: `var json = [{ "name": "A", "total": "40" }, { "name": "B", "total": "70" }, { "name": "C", "toatal": "90" }].map(function (point) { point.y = parseFloat(point.total); return point; });`

Comment: ohk.. right, Thanks Pawel.. It works for me.. Thanks a lot.